SeleniumBase - Unable to select a value from a dropdown using value, text,index
I am working on automating my workflows in SeleniumBase + Python. I am facing issues with this specific webpage , where I want to click on the dropdown and choose a value from the list of options presented to us.
I have tried using the methods :
self.click('//*[@id="-1_PersonProfileFields.AddressCountry"]')
self.send_keys("India")

self.select_option_by_index("//*[@id='-1_PersonProfileFields.AddressCountry']",45)

self.click('select#-1_PersonProfileFields.AddressCountry')
self.send_keys("India")

However , I face NoSuchElementException errors with each method.
The entire code is mentioned below :
from seleniumbase import BaseCase,Driver
import time
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_demo_site(self):
      self.get("https://careers-se.icims.com/jobs/67282/area-sales-manager---distributor/candidate?from=login&eem=VALI7WbuYjsYNVeTcJFe1Lp4NyzhJKL%252BgGk896dMArDy6SnRigcgxLtwQv3zbEEv&code=d4da33efe18fb5649da3012875a78ef45945b558aebf7cc0ab3716dce83614e7&ga=c2c2d57aa55f3a4b29a0cfc15e12e9e57cc3deaa024a3a5bc8be5724f93cc0b2&accept_gdpr=1&gdpr_consent_type=37002057002")
      time.sleep(5)
      self.switch_to_frame_of_element("//*[@id='PersonProfileFields.FirstName']")
      self.type("//*[@id='PersonProfileFields.FirstName']","Saul")
      time.sleep(10)
      self.select_option_by_index("//[@id='-1_PersonProfileFields.AddressCountry']",45)
      input("Continue")

Please let me know where I have made the mistake and how to rectify them.
Thank You !

Here's the https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase script for that:
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_career_page(self):
      self.get("https://careers-se.icims.com/jobs/67282/area-sales-manager---distributor/candidate?from=login&eem=VALI7WbuYjsYNVeTcJFe1Lp4NyzhJKL%252BgGk896dMArDy6SnRigcgxLtwQv3zbEEv&code=d4da33efe18fb5649da3012875a78ef45945b558aebf7cc0ab3716dce83614e7&ga=c2c2d57aa55f3a4b29a0cfc15e12e9e57cc3deaa024a3a5bc8be5724f93cc0b2&accept_gdpr=1&gdpr_consent_type=37002057002")
      self.switch_to_frame("#icims_content_iframe")
      self.type("//*[@id='PersonProfileFields.FirstName']", "Saul")
      self.click('a span[id*="Fields.AddressCountry"] span')
      self.type('[id*="Fields.AddressCountry"] input', "India")
      self.click('[id*="Fields.AddressCountry"] li[title="India"]')

      breakpoint()

I did some optimization too. I'm the maintainer of SeleniumBase, so I know a few things. :)

Hey Michael , thank you for your expertise . The code for clicking on the dropdown worked perfectly fine. However , the code for switching frame didnt work and I had to revert back to the old code I had written for switching the frame.

Odd, working for me. Although you can swap that line with self.switch_to_frame_of_element('span[id*="Fields.AddressCountry"]') if it works. Maybe a GeoLocation / Locale difference.

Thanks Michael ! Could you also let me know how did you code this line :
'[id*="Fields.AddressCountry"] input', "India"

The *= is the wildcard. It lets you use a partial attribute match, in this case for the ID. First I found the ID of the element, then I truncated it.

Thank You Michael ! If you don't mind , Im facing issues where if this dropdown contains any values , the code is not able to click on this dropdown or clear it. Do you know how to fix this ?

Is the example code not working for you anymore. You have to click on that span first, then type into the input before clicking the li.

According to the docs, you should be using
self.switch_to_frame("iframe")

to switch to an IFRAME.
So your code should look like
class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_demo_site(self):
      self.get(...)
      self.switch_to_frame("#icims_content_iframe") # this line was updated
      self.type("//*[@id='PersonProfileFields.FirstName']", "Saul")
      self.click("//a[@id='-1_PersonProfileFields.AddressCountry_icimsDropdown']")
      self.type("[aria-controls='-1_PersonProfileFields.AddressCountry_dropdown-results']", "India")
      self.click("li[title='India']")
      ...

When you are done working in that IFRAME, make sure you call self.switch_to_default_content() to come back out of the IFRAME context.

Hey JeffC ,
The other query ,viz to enter data in the first name field works perfectly fine. But I'm not able to select the required option from the dropdown.Since both the elements are present In the same frame , it shouldn't cause any issues, right ?

You are correct that since the dropdown element is in the same IFRAME that it should work. The problem here is that there is a SELECT element but it's hidden on the page so you can't use the typical .select_option_by_index() to choose a dropdown option. Instead you have to click the A tag that opens the dropdown, search for "India" in the dropdown searchbox, and then click the "India" option. I've updated my answer to handle this scenario.

thank you so much jeffc , however as I mentioned in the below answer , the code to switch frames is not working as it is. Please feel free to let me know if there are any updates regarding that.

What is the error when you run my code? and on what line is this error thrown?

Hey JeffC,
The code for iframe was on line 24 FYI. The error log is given below :
SE_base.py:24: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../../../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/seleniumbase/fixtures/base_case.py:3457: in switch_to_frame
    page_actions.switch_to_frame(self.driver, frame, timeout)
../../../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/seleniumbase/fixtures/page_actions.py:1428: in switch_to_frame
    timeout_exception(Exception, message)

exception = <class 'Exception'>, message = 'Frame {#icims_content_iframe} was not visible after 10 seconds!'
def timeout_exception(exception, message):
    exc, msg = shared_utils.format_exc(exception, message)


  raise exc(msg)


E       Exception: Frame {#icims_content_iframe} was not visible after 10 seconds!
../../../Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/seleniumbase/fixtures/page_actions.py:252: Exception

Also the code self.click('a span[id*="Fields.AddressCountry"] span') is throwing NoSuchElementException error
